# How to show original string after XSS in vex dialog?

Tags: javascript

[Edit] I'm not trying to create xss, I'm trying to show the message at vex dialog.

[Edit] document.createTextNode() do the trick

I want to show unescaped character at ***vex dialog***.

But I can't find a way to do what I want, my string is being filterXSS.

How can I show the original message at vex dialog?

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Example CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/wispy-silence-5xmvp?fontsize=14

Comment: `<script>`s don’t run when inserted with `innerHTML`. (Not a security thing, that’s just how it is.) You can use `<img src="foo" onerror="alert('Cool')">` instead.

Comment: That's a cool thing, but I actually want to show the message at vex dialog, not trying to insert executable script tag at HTML.

Comment: Oh gosh, sorry. That it doesn’t work with `message` is probably a bug in the library.